# What wire to use for about five 5 V 1 A continuous servo motors in parallel?

Tags: power-supply, arduino, circuit-design, wiring, servo

I am not particularly familiar with electronics and circuits in general although I do have some basic experience.

My concern is that to carry enough current for all five motors I would need at least 5 amps, which the wire that the servo already has sticking out of it can not handle (looks to be about 28 AWG). Is it okay to connect the wire coming off the servo to some 18 AWG wire or is that likely to generate a lot of heat?

Also I'm not sure if I should go with solid core or stranded wire and any advice on power supplies would be much appreciated too, I really don't want to use batteries.

Sorry for poor formatting and long winded question, I have never done this before and am posting from my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would depend on a few things, are they in parallel or series? I would recommend parallel. They all take 5V 1A so 5A total so you'll be looking for 20 gauge wire according to wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge

I imagine 18 gauge will work too though, depending on your power source, if it's current limited or not, but no it shouldn't generate excessive heat.

As far as I know stranded can generally carry more current for a specific gauge, but that's pretty much all I can give you because the question is somewhat vague or maybe I'm overthinking it.

Good luck

Comment: My main question is whether or not i can run the servos in parallel off a higher gauge wire holding more current then the wires attached to the servo can handle. But thankyou for the input.

Comment: yes you can, because the servos will act like a current splitter